# Copy and deepcopy not working on/with a lambda function?

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, deep-copy

Here is a minimum example of my code that triggers the error:

```
x = np.array([0.       , 2.0943951, 4.1887902])

coeffs = np.array([[-0.08952269,  1.59581565, -0.55240446],
                    [ 2.33359441, -0.71809073,  0.        ]])

quadratic_spline = piecewise_polynomial(coeffs, x)
print(quadratic_spline(3))

coeffs = np.array([[ 0.06200785,  0.60701535, -0.        , -0.06631379],
                   [-1.15644773,  2.3523244 , -0.83332369,  0.06631379]])

print(quadratic_spline(3))
```

This is the output:

```
0.17932221999999998

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/lib/condor/execute/dir_1389034/ipykernel_1403467/1828880745.py in <module>
     10                    [-1.15644773,  2.3523244 , -0.83332369,  0.06631379]])
     11 
---> 12 print(quadratic_spline(3))

<string> in <lambda>(x, order, xs)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)
```

Here is the definition of `piecewise_polynomial`, I don't think the cause of the error is here, and I know it is very bad programming.

```
def piecewise_polynomial(coeffs, xs):
    """
    Given the coefficients of a piecewise polynomial in a single variable and the the limits of each piece, construct the function. 
    The basis functions for the polynomial are 1, x, x*x, x**2, ..., x**n, ...
    Doesn't work if the length of xs is too high, as the syntax will be too complex for the parser.
    
    Input:
    coeffs:np.2darray 
    xs:np.array
    
    Return:
    piecewise_polynomial:function float to float
    """
    coeffs = deepcopy(coeffs)
    function_str = f'lambda x, order={coeffs.shape[1]}, xs=np.{repr(xs)}: np.sum(np.array([x**n for n in range(order)])*coeffs[0]) if xs[0] <= x <= xs[1]'
    for i, x in enumerate(xs[1:-1], start=1):
        function_str += f' else (np.sum(np.array([x**n for n in range(order)])*coeffs[{i}]) if xs[{i}] < x <= xs[{i+1}]'
    
    function_str += f" else None{')'*(len(xs)-2)}"
    return eval(function_str)
```

I tried using `.copy` and `copy.deepcopy`:

- `quadratic_spline = piecewise_polynomial(coeffs.copy(), x)`
- `quadratic_spline = piecewise_polynomial(copy.deepcopy(coeffs), x)`
- `quadratic_spline = copy.deepcopy(piecewise_polynomial(coeffs, x))`

And some combinations, but got the same error message in each case. Only not reusing `coeffs` as a variable name averted the error.

I expect the output to be `0.17932221999999998` twice, and no more, at least when using `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: There has to be a better way than constructing a long conditional string and then using `eval()`.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to spend more time on it.

Comment: Well, you're gonna have to, because that's the source of the problem. Functions defined with `eval` don't have access to closure variables. `eval` is one of those beginner traps that looks *really enticing* to someone who doesn't know what they're doing, but actually requires an astonishing amount of expertise and weird edge case knowledge to use properly.

Comment: I don't know why you think this has anything to do with `copy.deepcopy`. Deepcopy is working just fine, the issue is *what variable is being resolved in the dynamically executed string*. copy/deepcopy never affects that. This is really important to understand

Comment: @user2357112 I agree with your sentiment, but in this case, passing in a namespace  to eval explicitly would work.